# File size limitations of ZipOutputStream?

Tags: java, stream, compression, zip

I am using the [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) to create ZIP files. It works fine, but the Javadoc is quite sparse, so I'm left with questions about the characteristics of ZipOutputStream:

1. Is there a limit for the maximum supported file sizes? Both for files contained in the ZIP and for the resulting ZIP file itself? The `size` argument is `long`, but who knows. (Let us assume that the filesystem imposes no limits.)
2. What is the minimum input file size that justifies use of the DEFLATED method?

I will always read the resulting ZIP file using [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Comment: How did you check that it has limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important aspect is that in a current Java-7 JDK, `ZipOutputStream` creates ZIP files according to [the 2012 PKZIP specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), which also includes support for ZIP64. Note that the ZIP64 features [had bugs at first](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077769), but any recent version of the Java 7 JDK will be OK.

1. The maximum file size is thus **2<sup>64</sup>-1 bytes**. I tried it with a 10 GB test file. This is much larger than the 4 GB of standard ZIP. I could add it to the ZIP file with no problems, also if the resulting ZIP file itself grew beyond 4 GB.
2. The minimum file size which justifies use of the DEFLATED method is **22 bytes**. This has nothing to do with the minimum ZIP file size which is incidentally also 22 bytes (for empty ZIP files). I empirically determined this number by adding strings of `a`s of increasing length (see diagram below). Such a sequence of identical characters compresses very well, so in the real world, the break-even point will be higher.

[image: Deflated vs. Stored]

Comment: I'm glad to see the results of you taking my advice. +1

Answer (score 4):

Following are the limits of ZIP file format:

> The minimum size of a .ZIP file is 22 bytes. The maximum size for both
>   the archive file and the individual files inside it is 4,294,967,295
>   bytes (232−1 bytes, or 4 GiB minus 1 byte) for standard .ZIP, and
>   18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes (264−1 bytes, or 16 EiB minus 1 byte)
>   for ZIP64.[31]

Reference : [Zip (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29)